# matching values of 2 columns of different sizes in different files and returning corresponding value of third column of one of those files

Tags: r, merge

I have workbook with an overview file which contains information about each trial

```
    Trial   | date| time| call| social status
    Trial001 xxx   xxx    y     Single alone
    Trial002 xxx   xxx    n     pair with partner
    Trial003 xxx   xxx    n     pair with partner
```

and one workbook with a file containing different behaviours per individual (in rows) per trial. (different subjects between trials but due to BORIS all called F1)

```
    Subject | Trial    | behavior | total count | mean duration (S) | stdv 
    F1      | Trial001 | jump     | 1           | 5                 | stdv
    F1      | Trial001 | walk     | 2           | 10                | stdv
    F1      | Trial002 | jump     | 3           | 10                | stdv
    F1      | Trial002 | walk     | 3           | 10                | stdv
    F1      | Trial002 | no view  | 3           | 50                | stdv
```

Now i want to make a column in the behaviour file containing the social status mentioned in the corresponding overview trial.

I thought `left_join` would fix my issue but when i try this it gives me an error saying it need `~name` or it returns my entire mutating join code to my console instead of filling the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I'm overwriting the data.frame `behavior`, with the result of the join

```
behavior <- behavior %>%
  left_join(overview %>% select(Trial, social_status),
            by="Trial")
```

Output:

```
  Subject Trial    behavior total_count mean_duration stdv  social_status    
  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>         <dbl> <chr> <chr>            
1 F1      Trial001 jump               1             5 stdv  Single alone     
2 F1      Trial001 walk               2            10 stdv  Single alone     
3 F1      Trial002 jump               3            10 stdv  pair with partner
4 F1      Trial002 walk               3            10 stdv  pair with partner
5 F1      Trial002 no view            3            50 stdv  pair with partner
```

Input:

```
# Behavior
structure(list(Subject = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1"), Trial = c("Trial001", 
"Trial001", "Trial002", "Trial002", "Trial002"), behavior = c("jump", 
"walk", "jump", "walk", "no view"), total_count = c(1, 2, 3, 
3, 3), mean_duration = c(5, 10, 10, 10, 50), stdv = c("stdv", 
"stdv", "stdv", "stdv", "stdv"), social_status = c("Single alone", 
"Single alone", "pair with partner", "pair with partner", "pair with partner"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

# overview
structure(list(Trial = c("Trial001", "Trial002", "Trial003"), 
    date = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx"), time = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx"
    ), call = c("y", "n", "n"), social_status = c("Single alone", 
    "pair with partner", "pair with partner")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```